# Library not loaded

Tags: xcode, mac, macos, c++, lib

Уважаемые форумчане!

Помогите исправить ошибку: я подключаю свою написанную динамическую библиотеку в консольное приложение, и получаю такую ошибку при запуске бинарника "test":

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/LibName.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/Documents/MyProj/Build/Release/test
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Как это исправить? Если класть файл LibName.dylib по адресу /usr/local/lib/, ошибка не исчезает.
Ну хоть кто-нибудь ответьте на этот простой вопрос!!!

Comment: Цитата из справки "Этот сайт посвящен исключительно получению ответов. Это не форум для дискуссий."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено!!!
Во-первых, в свойствах проекта нужно указывать, по какому адресу расположена библиотека:

**Build Settings -> Linking -> Dynamic Library Install Name -> $(EXECUTABLE_PATH)**  
**Build Settings -> Linking -> Dynamic Library Install Name Base -> $(EXECUTABLE_PATH)**

Во-вторых, при загрузке библиотеки с помощью функции dlopen(), необходимо указывать абсолютный путь к ней с именем самой библиотеки. И третье, и самое главное, в чём была ошибка - НЕ ДОБАВЛЯЙТЕ библиотеку в **Link Binary With Libraries**!!! Этот раздел используется для СТАТИЧЕСКИХ библиотек.